# Consultas en Sequelize, WHERE y INCLUDE

Tags: sequelize.js

me podrían ayudar en esta consulta. ya que funciona una opción de Sequelize.
quito uno y funciona el otro. pero no logro que funcione los dos juntos. es decir el where y los include

```
let list = await db.Productos.findOne(
            {
                where: { id: 1}
            },
            {
                include: [
                    { model: db.Colores },
                    { model: db.Categorias },
                    { model: db.Imagenes }
                ]
            }
        )
```

esta es la respuesta de la consulta pero quiero que me agregue las relaciones

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "escritorio",
        "stock": 4,
        "p_compra": 20000,
        "p_venta": 30000,
        "modelo": "",
        "alto": 12,
        "ancho": 233,
        "profundidad": 23,
        "descripcion": "2",
        "codigo": "233",
        "estado": 1,
        "createdAt": "2022-07-14T19:31:56.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-07-14T20:30:14.000Z"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione. ahí dejo la solución por si alguien le sirva

```
let list = await db.Productos.findByPk(1,
            {
                include: [{ model: db.Colores },
                { model: db.Categorias },
                { model: db.Imagenes }]
            }
        )
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente tu código. Lee [answer]. Luego [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.